# Can I deploy my Django application only using nginx or Gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I knew that for deploying a Django application we have to use a combination of uWSGI + Nginx or Nginx + Gunicorn server. Is that necessary? I have a small doubt here. Can we deploy the entire application only in Nginx or only in Gunicorn? Will, it not work? Just for an example(leaving production) can't I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES , you can. NO, you shouldn't.**

If you run your app (in my case Django), on its development server. You can access it from a remote computer at its ip_address:port_number which should look something like 123.142.524.110:8000 and you can see your app at work.

You can also run Django with only gunicorn, it will still lack the web servers capabilities like sering static files efficiently or handling slow clients or DDOS handling. But it will run and that is all I can promise.

Unsure of whether Nginx can be directly tried with DJANGO app server, but I don't see why not. <<Probably someone else can attest to having successfully 'tried' it>>

I should repeat again, just coz its possible doesn't mean you should do it.